# Folium choropleth example; combining DataFrame with json data

Tags: python, folium, choropleth

I have a question about the use of the choropleth method in folium.  I have a DataFrame that I want to use a basis for colors, it looks like this:

[image]

I also have a json file that contains district boundaries in the city.  At present, my choropleth is not coloring based on the `num` column of my DataFrame which is what I aim to accomplish.  Here is my code for generating the map:

```py
import json
import requests

url = 'http://data.beta.nyc//dataset/472dda10-79b3-4bfb-9c75-e7bd5332ec0b/resource/d826bbc6-a376-4642-8d8b-3a700d701557/download/88472a1f6fd94fef97b8c06335db60f7nyccommunitydistricts.geojson'

geo_json_data = json.loads(requests.get(url).text)

m = folium.Map([start[0], start[1]], zoom_start=9.5, tiles = 'Stamen Toner')

m.choropleth(geo_json_data, data = noise_plot, columns=['lat', 'long', 'num'], key_on='feature.id', fill_color= 'YlGn')

m
```

where `noise_plot` is the DataFrame in the image.  Here is what I see.  I think I am using the `key_on` argument incorrectly but not sure.  Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One approach that solved this was to adjust my GeoJson file to one that contained the zip code information and just map to this in order to color the regions.  Despite this, I imagine there are times when you have to use a `lat` and `lon` pair to match -- would be more curious about a solution here.

Comment: Can you please share your solution that worked?